# Kotlin Jetpack Compose - Textfield not accepting Inputs

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, android-jetpack-compose

I have a feature where after fetch data in firestore, it will display the it in the UI, but now i wanted to add a feature where if i click the edit button it will allow the users to edit it, however it seems not to accept UserInputs, Here is my code

```
                LazyColumn(
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .fillMaxWidth()
                        .padding(horizontal = 16.dp)
                ) {
                    item {
                        if (firefighters != null) {
                            for (firefighter in firefighters) {

                                var contactNumber = firefighter.contactNumber
                                val documentId = firefighter.documentId
                                var editedContactNumber = remember { contactNumber }

                                Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(5.dp))
                                Column {
                                    Text(
                                        text = "$documentId",
                                        color = Color.Black,
                                        style = LocalTextStyle.current,
                                        modifier = Modifier
                                            .paddingFromBaseline(
                                                10.dp,
                                                0.dp
                                            ) // Adjust vertical spacing as needed
                                    )


                                    Row(
                                        modifier = Modifier
                                            .fillMaxWidth()
                                            .height(50.dp)
                                            .padding(5.dp),
                                        horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.SpaceBetween
                                    ) {
                                        var isEditing by remember { mutableStateOf(false) }

                                        Box(
                                            modifier = Modifier
                                                .size(width = 150.dp, height = 40.dp)
                                                .border(2.dp, Color.Black)
                                                .background(Color.White),
                                            contentAlignment = Alignment.Center
                                        ) {
                                            if (isEditing) {
                                                TextField(
                                                    value = if (isEditing) editedContactNumber else "", // Show editedContactNumber if editing, otherwise show an empty string
                                                    onValueChange = { newValue ->
                                                        // Check if the input is not empty and contains only numeric characters
                                                        if (newValue.isNotEmpty() && newValue.all { char -> char.isDigit() }) {
                                                            // Check if the length is less than or equal to 11 digits
                                                            if (newValue.length <= 11) {
                                                                editedContactNumber = newValue
                                                                contactNumber = editedContactNumber
                                                                contactNumber = newValue


                                                            } else {
                                                                Log.d("editedContactNumber", "editedContactNumber: Number Input is not Valid ")
                                                            }
                                                        } else {
                                                            Log.d("EditInput", "Empty Field")
                                                        }
                                                        // You can provide feedback to the user or handle other cases as needed
                                                    },
                                                    textStyle = LocalTextStyle.current.copy(color = Color.Black, fontSize = 14.sp),
                                                    keyboardOptions = KeyboardOptions.Default.copy(
                                                        keyboardType = KeyboardType.Number
                                                    ),
                                                    modifier = Modifier.border(
                                                        width = 2.dp,
                                                        color = when {
                                                            editedContactNumber.isEmpty() && !isEditing -> Color.Red // Display red border for empty input if not in editing mode
                                                            editedContactNumber.length > 11 -> Color.Red // Display red border for more than 11 digits
                                                            else -> Color.Black
                                                        }
                                                    )
                                                )


                                            } else {
                                                Text(
                                                    text = if (isEditing) {
                                                        editedContactNumber
                                                    } else {
                                                        contactNumber
                                                    },
                                                    color = Color.Black,
                                                    style = LocalTextStyle.current
                                                )
                                            }
                                        }

                                        Icon(
                                            imageVector = if (isEditing) Icons.Default.Check else Icons.Default.Edit,
                                            contentDescription = null,
                                            tint = Color.Black,
                                            modifier = Modifier
                                                .size(24.dp)
                                                .align(Alignment.Bottom)
                                                .padding(bottom = 1.dp)
                                                .clickable {
                                                    if (!isEditing) {
                                                        editedContactNumber = contactNumber
                                                    }
                                                    isEditing = !isEditing

                                                    if (!isEditing) {
                                                        if (editedContactNumber.length == 11) {
                                                            // Update the contact number in Firestore
                                                            if (finalMunicipalityForm != null) {

                                                                val db = Firebase.firestore
                                                                db.collection("Emergency Contacts")
                                                                    .document("$finalMunicipalityForm")
                                                                    .collection("Firefighters")
                                                                    .document(documentId)
                                                                    .update(
                                                                        "contacts",
                                                                        editedContactNumber
                                                                    )
                                                                    .addOnSuccessListener {
                                                                        Log.d(
                                                                            "EditNumber",
                                                                            "Number updated successfully : $editedContactNumber"
                                                                        )
                                                                        isEditing = false
                                                                        editedContactNumber = ""
                                                                        context.showToast("Number Updated")
                                                                    }
                                                                    .addOnFailureListener { e ->
                                                                        Log.e(
                                                                            "EditNumber",
                                                                            "Error updating number",
                                                                            e
                                                                        )
                                                                    }
                                                            } else {
                                                                context.showToast("Please enter a 11-digit number")
                                                            }
                                                        }
                                                    }
                                                }
                                        )

                                        Icon(
                                            imageVector = Icons.Default.LocationOn,
                                            contentDescription = null,
                                            tint = Color.Black,
                                            modifier = Modifier
                                                .size(40.dp)
                                                .clickable {
                                                    userLocation?.let { location ->
                                                        // Call a function to handle sending SMS with location and phone number
                                                        sendLocationSMS(
                                                            context = context,
                                                            location = location,
                                                            phoneNumber = contactNumber
                                                        )
                                                    } ?: run {
                                                        Log.w(
                                                            "Clickable",
                                                            "User location is null"
                                                        )
                                                    }
                                                }
                                        )

                                        Spacer(modifier = Modifier.width(2.dp))

                                        Icon(
                                            imageVector = Icons.Default.Phone,
                                            contentDescription = null,
                                            tint = Color.Black,
                                            modifier = Modifier
                                                .size(40.dp)
                                                .clickable {
                                                    // Launch the dialer here
                                                    val dialIntent = Intent(
                                                        Intent.ACTION_DIAL,
                                                        Uri.parse("tel:$contactNumber")
                                                    )
                                                    dialerLauncher.launch(dialIntent)
                                                }
                                        )
                                    }

                                    Spacer(
                                        modifier = Modifier
                                            .height(1.dp)
                                            .fillMaxWidth()
                                            .background(Color.Black)
                                    )

                                    Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(5.dp))
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
```

Other Functionalities such as the phone and the share location are working perfectly, i just wanted to edit yet it does not allow me to input a new number

Comment: What exactly in this code doesn't work the way you expect?
Tell us what is wrong with shared code. Do you have any errors?

Comment: @AlexMamo apologies, the answer provided below by  fixed my problem. this thread is now close thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

maybe you forgot to use `mutableStateOf()` in this code `var editedContactNumber = remember { contactNumber }`.

If you want to do recomposition every `editedContactNumber` is changed you need to use `mutableStateOf()`.

So, the code will be like this  `val editedContactNumber = remember { mutableStateOf(contactNumber) }`. Please also read again about recomposition in this [link](https://dev.to/zachklipp/remember-mutablestateof-a-cheat-sheet-10ma).